# Trying to Print the Text from a Single Row of a Table if Row Contains Text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to print a row in a table if it contains the text that I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I've only been able to get it to print the text from the first cell of that row instead of the entire row.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
MyText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//*[contains(text(), 'Text I'm Looking For')]")

print(MyText.text)
```

What do I need to change so that all the text in that row prints instead of just the first cell?

Answer (score 0):

Change your xpath as below.

```
MyText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//*[contains(text(), 'Text I'm Looking For')]]")
print(MyText)
```

**Sample Screenshot:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: For some reason it printed every line in the table when I tried that. I altered my code to grab just one cell in the row I wanted like this:

```python
TextIWant = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr//*[contains(text(), 'Text I Want')]//following::td[4]")
```

This did work and returned just the text of that one cell.

Comment: You wanted to print the text in row, that's why we wrapped the `td` in `tr` xpath.  If you want the text from `td` then need that change in the xpath.

Comment: If you believe the issue is resolved please accept the answer and  [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers

Comment: I do still want to print the entire row, the above answer printed all of the rows instead of just that row however. I just wanted to try to print an individual cell so I could possibly string them all together. I may just do that.

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple rows matching the xpath I shared in answer and you want to print each matching row text?

Comment: @Loons22 : Please post relevant html on original post.Its really confuse OP to give you resolution without knowing what you would like to achieve.